# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-9

I'm having some issues with installing `vue-router` with `laravel`. `Laravel 9`, `Vue.js 3`

[image: console logger]

**routes.js**

```
import AllBooks from './components/AllBooks.vue';
import CreateBook from './components/CreateBook.vue';
import EditBook from './components/EditBook.vue';

export const routes = [
    {
        name: 'home',
        path: '/',
        component: AllBooks
    },
    {
        name: 'create',
        path: '/create',
        component: CreateBook
    },
    {
        name: 'edit',
        path: '/edit/:id',
        component: EditBook
    }
];
```

Here's my config:-

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
const app = createApp({})

import App from './App.vue';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import  VueRouter from 'vue-router'; // problem!!
import axios from 'axios';
import { routes } from './routes';

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    // 4. Provide the history implementation to use. We are using the hash history for simplicity here.
    history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
})

// Make sure to _use_ the router instance to make the
// whole app router-aware.
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.1",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    },
 "dependencies": {
        "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
        "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
    }
```

If you could help me with `vue-router` doesn't provide an export?

`import  VueRouter from '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=05a616f1';`

Comment: Looks like some incompatibility between a Vue 2 and 3 config.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, look out for duplicated entries for our vue libraries. I had:-

**resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
```

AND

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
   "vue": "^3.2.45",
   "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
}
```

also, my config changed in:-

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';

import * as Vue from 'vue';
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router'; // alternative ways of importing

import LoginComponent from "./components/LoginComponent.vue";
import TestComponent from "./components/TestComponent.vue";

const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/login', name: "Login", component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '/test', name: "Test", component: TestComponent },
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
})

const app = Vue.createApp({})

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

If this helps you, well keep truckin. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just from the **router.js** file

import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";

I deleted these and it worked

Answer (score 0):

your problem comes from VueRouter import for solving it you can do the following:

```
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';
```